# FourierTransform 1/(1 - Exp [I x])

Tags: fft

I have tried software like Wolfram Mathematica to find Fourier transform of this function

```
1/(1 - Exp [I x])
```

But Mathematica can not find Fourier transform of this function, I want to know that is there any mathematical method for finding Fourier transform of this function.